# mnrval Matlab function in R

Tags: r, matlab, statistics, logistic-regression, multinomial

Can someone please help me with the equivalent of the mnrval function in R? I have not been able to find one where predicted probabilities are returned based on arguments, coefficient estimates and predictor values. I tried to rewrite the Matlab function in R but was unable to because one of the inner functions that was used was private. I would highly appreciate your help on this.

The [documentation page on `mnrval()`](https://mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrval.html) states

> MNRVAL Predict values for a nominal or ordinal multinomial regression model.
> `PHAT = MNRVAL(B,X)` computes predicted probabilities for the nominal
> multinomial logistic regression model with predictor values X.  B is the
> intercept and coefficient estimates as returned by the MNRFIT function.  X
> is an N-by-P design matrix with N observations on P predictor variables.
> MNRVAL automatically includes intercept (constant) terms in the model; do
> not enter a column of ones directly into X.  PHAT is an N-by-K matrix of
> predicted probabilities for each multinomial category.

Comment: *" I tried to rewrite the Matlab function in R but was unable to"* Please share your code attempt. You should also include details as to what `mnrval` does (for those of us who are not familiar with Matlab). Best is sample data and expected output (along with your function attempt).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the function definition from Matlab, my code is incomplete so it is probably useless, there is a function called stattestlink in Matlab, when I get to that I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I would think that the R equivalent is something like `predict(multinom.fit, newdata = test, "class")` where `multinom.fit` is the model and `test` is a data frame for prediction, with the same format as the data used to train the model. [This tutorial](https://datasciencebeginners.com/2018/12/20/multinomial-logistic-regression-using-r/) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My issue is I don't have the multinom.fit object because the model has already been fit in Matlab by someone else and I don't have access to that, I only have the coefficients and predictors.